# How to disable the disassembly window in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, disassembly

How can I prevent the CPU window from popping up when I'm debugging?
Is there a setting for this?
I'm using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you step into code that does not have debug information, then the disassembly window pops up. There's no way to disable that behaviour, to the best of my knowledge.

Instead you can circumvent this by simply providing debug information for all your units. For example, if you are stepping into RTL/VCL units, then build with the *Debug DCUs* option enabled.

Comment: Also if you're stepping into DLLs you're out of luck if they're not Delphi or you don't have source code, but if they are your own files then you can open and compile them both in the same project and Delphi will be able to step into the DLL as if it were the same codebase.

Comment: Alternatively, you can always just use `Step Over` instead of `Step Into` unless you are hitting a method that is known to be something you're interested in seeing the contents of and that you have debug information for.